# How to reliably capture Linux kernel log messages in case of a system debilitating crash (BUG, panic)?

Tags: logging, kernel, linux-kernel, debugging, kernel-panic

I'd like to have access to the lines/tracebacks/whatever whispered by the kernel right before dying. This has proven problematic, because all interfaces I have access to become disabled. Post-reboot, systemd journal has not been able to record anything about the crash, probably because flushing buffers to filesystem is blocked.

Here's what I've tried and failed with

1. console access - X application runs here for dayjob, but after system has crashed, no keyboard input is recognized, so I can't switch to vt
2. `netconsole` sending data to `nc` listening on another machine - I expected this to work, but while everything else shows up, no crash-related kernel tracebacks get there, not even with `dmesg -n 8`
3. `ssh` via network - impossible after the crash, because network gets blocked off, too

What other option do I have to capture 100% everything? Perhaps serial console? (what would be a suitable device) I think anything with USB is susceptible to also getting the subsystem blocked off.

**Note**: This box is local, sitting in my room, so all access and methods are available.

Comment: If you had out of band management you could see the console remotely. Without legacy ports, there are USB serial adapters.

Comment: try `pstore`: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/pstore